# File defining the service assigned to each port

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

I know there are already `nmap` and `netstat` commands we could use to see all open port on Ubuntu. However, I know there exists a file with all port and the service assign to each port. Could anyone have an idea what is that file and where could I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this file:

```
/etc/services
```

Comment: Yessss, exactly!!